# Angular JS routing priority

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie and just get few days of working with AngularJS.
The thing I am concerning right now is priority of routing path of the $routeProvider and how to arrange them correctly.
As bellow code:

```
    routingApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/showOrder/:id', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })  ....
```

with a url includes params like "http://localhost:3000/routing_01.html#/showOrder/123", the template is appears
But without params, I can't see a template
Could you help me understand the priority of routing paths in $routeProvider and how to managed them correctly.
(I did search google but so badluck...:( )

JavaScript code

```
    var routingApp = angular
        /**
         *  Module
         *
         * Description
         */
        .module('routingApp', []);

    routingApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })
                .when('/showOrder/:id', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })
                .when('/displayOrder/:id', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/display_order.html',
                    controller: 'DisplayOrderController'
                })
                .otherwise({

                })
        }
    ]);

    routingApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
        console.log("ShowOrderController");
        $scope.orderId = $routeParams.orderId;
    });

    routingApp.controller('DisplayOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
        console.log("DisplayOrderController");
        $scope.orderId = $routeParams.orderId;
    });
```

HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <html class="no-js">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    </head>

    <body ng-app="routingApp">
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->
        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <p>Using angular Routing</p>
        <a href="#showOrder">Show Order</a>
        <a href="#displayOrder">Display Order</a>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')
        </script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/routing_01.js"></script>
        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
        (function(b, o, i, l, e, r) {
            b.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l;
            b[l] || (b[l] =
                function() {
                    (b[l].q = b[l].q || []).push(arguments)
                });
            b[l].l = +new Date;
            e = o.createElement(i);
            r = o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)
        }(window, document, 'script', 'ga'));
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without params"? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens insead?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't see any template?

Comment: The page did not load a template...I did check it via console network of Chrome. Dear @OlatundeGaruba

Comment: Dear @JBNizet: incase the URL without parameter, the template disappeared.

Comment: Tell us what you mean by "the URL without parameter", precisely.

Comment: the URL without param is:
http://localhost:3000/routing_01.html#/showOrder.
"123" is request params and within parameter, the URL is
http://localhost:3000/routing_01.html#/showOrder/123

Comment: So, your question is: why does it not display anything when using `/showOrder` as the path. The answer is simple: because it doesn't match any of the route URLs: `/` is not equal to `/showOrder`; `/showOrder/:id`doesn't match `/showOrder`, since it expects `/showOrder` followed by a `/` followed by an ID; and `/displayOrder/:id` doesn't match `/showOrder` either, obviously.

Comment: Thank... totally different with ExpressJS...:)..thank you very much @JBNizet

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually quite simple: You have not defined a route to a template without the params. I think you can fix it like this:

```
routingApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })
                .when('/showOrder', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })
                .when('/displayOrder', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/display_order.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })
                .when('/showOrder/:id', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
                })
                .when('/displayOrder/:id', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/display_order.html',
                    controller: 'DisplayOrderController'
                })
                .otherwise({

                })
        }
    ]);
```

You need to add the route without the parameter in order to see the template if you do not pass the parameter. However, do mind that the parameter (if you use it in your template) will not be available if you don't pass it (which is kind of logical :-) )

So in other words: what  JB Nizet said in a comment (he beat me to it).

Comment: It is working...vote for you and thank very much @ocket-san